# How to Pass JSON Object through Url

Tags: android

```
{"value":"CUSTOM","allow":"ALL_FRIENDS","deny":"100000415571929,1340463778"}
```

I need to send this to this data as a http request,I am getting Illegal character errors.

How to send these special characters?

Thanks

Comment: You should be sending this as a post or put body, not in the URL.

Comment: i'm pretty sure that you don't wana send this data through Url ...

Comment: Yes, I used String result = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(deniedfriends);

Comment: @user1891910 if my given solution helps you to solve your problem then you can accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `URLEncoder` class, it should work

```
String url = "http://example.com/query?q=" + URLEncoder.encode("{\"value\":\"CUSTOM\",\"allow\":\"ALL_FRIENDS\",\"deny\":\"100000415571929,1340463778\"}", "ISO-8859-1");
```

Hope I didn't miss any scape character :P

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way :

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postURL);

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value","CUSTOM"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("allow","ALL_FRIENDS"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("deny","100000415571929,1340463778"));

UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,HTTP.UTF_8);
post.setEntity(ent);
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.